# QWebEngineView constructor silently exits

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qt5.6

For a Windows computer without the necessary OpenGL capabilities, trying to create a `QWebEngineView` object silently causes the process to `exit()`. There is no error message, no exception, but just an exit. My question is how to catch this condition in order to tell the user to update the OpenGL drivers?

Comment: Try destructors of static C++ objects or the `atexit()` function.

Comment: Agree that's an answer to the question as I stated it, but I actually meant how to catch the condition that triggers the exit() before it is called. I can then turn off the use of QWebEngineView and then start the application.

Comment: If you use gdb, try breakpoints on exit or _exit.